# Lucene idf calculation - is it number of documents in the index from all fields or just from the field in the query

Tags: lucene, tf-idf

Confused how IDF is calculated in Lucene while reading Elastic docs. There are two parts of it for IDF calculation:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/scoring-theory.html

How often does the term appear in all documents in the collection? The more often, the lower the weight. Common terms like and or the contribute little to relevance, as they appear in most documents, while uncommon terms like **elastic** or **hippopotamus** help us zoom in on the most interesting documents. The inverse document frequency is calculated as follows:

```
idf(t) = 1 + log ( numDocs / (docFreq + 1))
```

The inverse document frequency (idf) of term t is the logarithm of the number of documents in the index, divided by the number of documents that contain the term.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/relevance-intro.html
Inverse document frequency
How many times did the term **honeymoon** appear in the **tweet** field of all documents in the index?

**Here is my question:**
Lets say, I have indexed 3 documents with 5 fields where f1,f2,f3 are in doc1, f2,f3,f4 are in doc2 and f3,f4,f5 are in doc5. My query is against f2 field.

numDocs - is it all documents (#-3) or just documents where field is present (#-2)?
docFreq - this seems to be clear. I think it is number of documents with f2 field where this term matches. It may be 1 or 2.

Hope they include the text **per field** when they all documents. Thanks